# /etc/lsb-release: No such file or directory

Tags: linux, macos, unix

I am running a script written by someone else on Mac OSX. And, I'm getting this error
/etc/lsb-release: No such file or directory

I researched a bit and looks like this tells the program what Linux version it is. Obviously, it's not available on OSX. Any suggestions on what it should be changed to in OSX

EDIT: Here's the script https://github.com/reddit/reddit/blob/master/install-reddit.sh

Comment: ...and that script written by someone else was clearly only written for Linux. How do you expect us to help you without getting into the guts of the script, since that's where the problem is?

Comment: Yeah. That *absolutely* won't work on MacOS. I mean, the very first thing it does after looking at the contents of `lsb_release` is bail if the distro is anything other than a very specific release of Ubuntu; after that, it installs a huge bunch of Ubuntu packages.

Comment: ...and after that, it pulls hardware info (memory info) out of `/proc` filesystem files that don't exist on anything but the Linux kernel.

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out. I should install a VM with Ubuntu then.

Answer (score 0):

A stub might look something like...

```
LSB_VERSION=1.4
DISTRIB_ID=MacOSX
DISTRIB_RELEASE=10.9
DISTRIB_DESCRIPTION="Not Linux"
```

...but any script that's trying to look for a Linux-only file is likely to have other problems on MacOS as well.

---

Install Ubuntu 12.04 on a virtual machine if you want that script to work.